# change some fragments by buttons and others by swiping inside the same viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I have viewpager with 5 scroll-able fragments, i would like to make 
fragment 1 load by default
fragment 2 accessed by button clicked in fragment 1
then allow user to scroll to frag.4(without bottoms)
frag. 5 displayed when user click button in frag. 4

is it possible to do that?
thanks in advance

```
main activity::
package com.example.s_meter.all.horizental;

import com.example.siemenssmartmeter.R;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;

public class SMeterAllHorrzental extends ActionBarActivity{

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.s_meter_all_h);

        MyPageAdapter_all_h pageAdapter;
        ViewPager pager;



      pageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter_all_h(getSupportFragmentManager());
      pager =(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        final RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
        pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                switch (position){
                    case 0:
                        radioGroup.check(R.id.radioButton);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        radioGroup.check(R.id.radioButton2);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        radioGroup.check(R.id.radioButton3);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        radioGroup.check(R.id.radioButton4);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        radioGroup.check(R.id.radioButton5);
                        break;

                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
        pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);




}
}
```

adapter::::

```
package com.example.s_meter.all.horizental;
import com.example.horizental.tabs_s_old.*;
import com.example.s.meter.tabs.Location_tab;
import com.example.s.meter.tabs.New_meter;

import java.util.List;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class MyPageAdapter_all_h extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    //private List<Fragment> fragments;
    //  public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
    public MyPageAdapter_all_h(FragmentManager fm) {
      super(fm);
     // this.fragments = fragments;
    }
    @Override 
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
     // return this.fragments.get(position);
        Fragment f=null;
        if(position ==0){
            f=new Location_tab();
        }
        else if(position ==1){
            f=new Old_meter_frag1();
        }
        else if (position==2){
            f=new Old_meter_frag2();
        }
        else if (position==3){
            f=new Old_meter_frag3();
        }
        else if (position==4){
            f=new New_meter();
        }

        return f;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
      return 5;
    }
}
```

Comment: is it possible that you show some code?

Comment: yes sure, i have added the code